# New Install: Blender 2.93 won't open on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation

All I'm getting is a crash window.
This is NEW install (I have never installed Blender on this computer before). Install seems to complete smoothly but when I go to open Blender it crashes immediately.
My setup meets Blender's recommended requirements.
Here's what happens when I clock on Blender:
The CMD window pops up briefly before it crashes. Managed to capture it quickly:
[image]